# How do I select all parenting items based on a given node's attribute in php's xPath?

Tags: php, xpath, design-patterns

Thanks to AakashM, he led me in the right direction. For the question below, this is the xPath expression that led me the right way:

```
"//channel/item[category[@domain='http://www.somelink.com/?category=4']]"
```

**Original post:**

I have an XML feed that looks something like this (excerpt):

```
<channel>
  <title>Channel Name</title>
  <link>Link to the channel</link>

    <item>
      <title>Heading 1</title>
      <link>http://www.somelink.com?id=100</link>
      <description><![CDATA[ Text here ]]></description>
      <publishDate>Fri, 03 Apr 2009 10:00:00</publishDate>
      <guid>http://www.somelink.com/read-story-100</guid>
      <category domain="http://www.somelink.com/?category=4">Category 1</category>
    </item>

    <item>
      <title>Heading 2</title>
      <link>http://www.somelink.com?id=110</link>
      <description><![CDATA[ Text here ]]></description>
      <publishDate>Fri, 03 Apr 2009 11:00:00</publishDate>
      <guid>http://www.somelink.com/read-story-110</guid>
      <category domain="http://www.somelink.com/?category=4">Category 1</category>
    </item>

  <channel>
```

That's the rough of it. I'm using this piece of PHP (excerpt):

```
$xml = simple_xml_load_file($xmlFile);
$xml->xpath($pattern);
```

Now I want to get all ITEM-nodes (with their children) based on that pesky "domain" attribute in the category node, but *no matter what I try it does-not-work*.

**The closest I got was "//category[@domain= 'http://www.somelink.com/?category=4']"**

The expression I tried gave me this result:

```
 [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [domain] => http://www.somelink.com/?category=4
                )

            [0] => Category 1

 [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [domain] => http://www.somelink.com/?category=4
                )

            [0] => Category 1
```

The expression should contain all childrens of the two items in the example, but as you can see only the info in the category node is present, I want all the item nodes.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Try and avoid using `//` when you know for sure the structure of your xml)

So you want all `item` nodes which have a `category` child node which in turn has a `domain` attribute with a particular value:

```
/channel/item[category[@domain='http://www.somelink.com/?category=4']]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The expression ran without errors, but the return set is empty. : /

Comment: @bakkelun — Most likely, you'll need to add additional element names to the beginning of the path to match your XML structure.  (e.g. If your `channel` is wrapped in a `feed`, the xpath should be changed to `/feed/channel/item[...]`.)  For testing, you could also temporarily change it to `//channel/item[...]`.

Comment: @bakkelun, oops I had `child` in the expression where I meant `category`. Edited; try it now?

Comment: Same as before, the expression ran, but the return set is empty :((

Comment: After 4 hours of getting nowhere, you Sir AakashM led me the right way. Here's the working one (See updated original post). I'll give you a granted solution to this one!